# Where are the sqlite drivers for monotouch?

Tags: c#, ios, sqlite, xamarin.ios, sqlite-net

On the sqlite-net [github page](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net), it indicates that in addition to this library, I also need the compiled sqlite2 binaries:

> 0 dependencies aside from a [compiled form of the sqlite2 library](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html).

I checked that page and I am unable to determine what binaries I should use in order to use it on IOS via MonoTouch; the instructions make it quite clear that this particular use-case was actually the genesis of this project, so this must be supported.

Does anyone know what binaries I am supposed to use on IOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Sqlite` - well, `Sqlite3` - is part of MonoTouch. In your project you'll need to reference `Mono.Data.Sqlite`. Right click "References" in your project in MonoDevelop, then select "Edit References".

[image: References]

Comment: Ok, well duh. :) I was trying it out on Windows and since I needed to acquire the drivers there, I had assumed I would on IOS as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

For sqlite-net on iOS, you don't need anything. It uses p/invoke calls and iOS supports SQLite, so it works out of the box.

Comment: Ok, well duh. :)  I was trying it out on Windows and since I needed to acquire the drivers there, I had assumed I would on IOS as well.  Thanks!